# Gradle transparently rename dependecy package

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies

Is it possible to create dependency, which on compile will be transparently repackaged?
My idea is as follows:

```
// project library
dependencies {
    compile 'some.library:artifact:version'
}

repackage {
    rule 'some.library.**' 'ext.library.**'
}

// main project, which uses directly "import ext.library.ClassName"
dependencies {
    compile project(':library')
}
```

also, related, my, unanswered question:

[Gradle rename maven dependency package (HttpComponents, Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19361128/gradle-rename-maven-dependency-package-httpcomponents-android)

Comment: so the idea is to resolve some.library:artifact:version but have some.library:artifact.** on your classpath, generated poms etc? or do you want to resolve ext.library here? can you elaborate a bit on your usecase?

Comment: @ReneGroeschke in fact it's similar to linked question, i want the project to depend on eg. "jackson json" library, which has package "com.fasterxml.jackson" but I want to refer to it on "main project" in java code as "com.slowxml.jackson", the form of dependency name doesn't matter, we're talking about re-packaging/renaming package within JAR dependency

Comment: Moving classes to another package is non-trivial, especially if reflection is used somewhere in those classes. You would need to read the bytecode of each class in the JAR, and then modify both its package and the package of its imported types. You would need to do this in another module and publish the repackaged JAR from that module. Then you can depend on the module that did the repackaging from the modules needing the repackaged classes.